# SQL Query LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of LIKE clause in query when wanting to use multiple terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910362/order-of-like-clause-in-query-when-wanting-to-use-multiple-terms)

I am attempting to make a search function on my website. I want to search more than one field.

for example:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from inventory WHERE MATCH (pn, description, location, notes) AGAINST ('{$q}')  ORDER BY {$sort} {$direction}") or die(mysql_error());
```

The above searches pn, description, location, and notes. But it only searches for exact matches. So I'm wanting to use:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from inventory where pn like '%{$q}%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

But search more than one field like the above. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: All you needed was `IN BOOLEAN MODE` in your fulltext style query. Example `... SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE MATCH (pn, description, location, notes) AGAINST ('{$q}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ORDER BY ...`